# Embedding t4 templates in plugin

Tags: templates, plugins, t4

I have created a plugin in VS 2012. This plugin solution contains T4 templates also. I have implemented the logic to execute t4 templates on click of plugin when the t4 templates are also present in the plugin solution.

Problem is how do i embed the T4 templates in plugin so that when we use this plugin in any other solution which does not contain these template files, then also on Click of plugin templates are executed and produce output files. I am attching code snippet I am using.

```
    var dte = Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.11.0") as EnvDTE80.DTE2;
    Solution sol = ((DTE)dte).Solution;
    string strFileName = string.Empty;
    foreach (Project project in sol.Projects)
    {
      foreach (ProjectItem item in project.ProjectItems)
      {                              
         if (item.Name.Contains(".tt"))
         {
            VSLangProj.VSProjectItem itemobj =(VSLangProj.VSProjectItem)item.Object;
            itemobj.RunCustomTool();                    
         }             
      }
    }
```

Posted By:Shivani Srivastava

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use the T4 service.  You can get an IServiceProvider from the DTE then  query for STextTemplating.  Docs for how to use that are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586947%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).